# How to replace NULL to specific string?

Tags: sql

Does anyone know how to replace NULL to specific string in PieCloudDB Database?

Before

| ID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 001 | Allen |
| 002 | Emma |
| 003 | NULL |
| 004 | NULL |

After

| ID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 001 | Allen |
| 002 | Emma |
| 003 | Undefined |
| 004 | Undefined |

I want to replace NULL with 'Undefined'.

Comment: Can't you simply use `COALESCE`? I have never used a PieCloudDB. But I don't know any RDBMS that doesn't support `COALESCE`.

Comment: do you want to change `NULL` to some text when executing a select query or you want to update the `NULL` value with some text in the table ?

Comment: Thank you, I'll try it. @JonasMetzler

Comment: I want to execute a SELECT query. @MuhammadZakaria

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NULL value could be replaced using the following functions: COALESCE：

I don't know if this function is suitable for the PieCloudDB database you are using. Maybe you can give it a try.

```
SELECT ID, COALESCE(Name, 'Undefined') AS Name FROM your_table;
```

If you want to change to other, you can simply modify the parameters 'Undefined' in your database.